# Turning string into time in excel

Tags: excel, time, timestamp, time-format

does somebody how I can turn this string:  `PT5H23M` into a usable time in excel? This should put out 5h 23 min?

Thank you.

Comment: side note: the format of the string is an [ISO 8601 duration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUBSTITUTE:

```
=--SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"M",":00"),"H",":"),"PT","")
```

Then format the output: `[hh]" h" mm" min"`

[image]

Comment: Thank you, the conversion with SUBSTITUTE works but it doesn't format as described. Mine stays at "5:23:00"

Comment: Nevermind, forgot the -- at the beginning. Thanks a lot.